# JPA batch insert causing ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I'm working on project where I use mainly EJB and JPA, but I have problem with ConstraintViolationException that should not happen.

First of all I have `MyEntity` class with @Id and few unique fields.
I have @Stateless `MyEntityRepository` class with `find()` method which just returns MyEntity (or null) by calling EntityManager get() method.
Another @Stateless bean is `SaveEntityBean`:

```
@Stateless
public class SaveEntityBean {

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;
    @Inject
    MyEntityRepository repository;

    public void saveEntity(MyEntity me) {
        if(repository.find(me) == null) {
            //the place with ConstraintViolationException
            em.persist(me);
        }
    }
    public void saveEntities(List<...> entities) {
        for(MyEntity me: entities)
            saveEntity(e);
    }
}
```

and the method `saveEntities(List<...> entities)` is called from another bean:

```
@Stateless
@Startup
public class SaveEntityBean {

    @Inject
    SaveEntityBean saveBean;
    //...

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second="*/5")
    @AccessTimeout(unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES, value = 1)
    public void mainLogicMethod() {
        List<MyEntity> entities = io.calculateAndGetEntities();
        saveBean.saveEntities(entities);
    }
}
```

where the `io.calculateAndGetEntities()` method is long IO work. The problem is that sometimes I get `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` which in my opinion should not occur, because I check `MyEntityRepository.find(me) != null` condition before calling persist() method.
The only idea I have is that there is some delay between commits, so after calling `MyEntityRepository.find(me)` method in condition check, the commit occurs, and just after that the `persist()` method throws the exception.

Please give me any suggestions what to read and learn and how to solve the problem.

edit:
I found that it is a problem with threading, so probably the solution is with locking write/read.

Comment: Indeed it looks like a synchronization issue - you have a check-then-act operation in saveEntity() and the mainLogicMethod() timer spawns threads.

Comment: I stopped reading when stumbling about the variable me and em in the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, generally in a high concurrent enviroment it is really hard to solve this problem and simply Locking will not work(and You don't want to use table locks). For now I use Hibernate `@SQLInsert` annotation from `org.hibernate.annotations.SQLInsert` so my Entity looks like this:

```
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO my_entity_table(a, b, c) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=a;")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {...}
```

Of course it will be problematic, when You would like to show some error message to the user, but in my case it is good enough.
As far as I know this SQL statement is supported only in MySQL, in other RDBMS you should use different aproach.